# Why does the type error appear if the column is clear?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, nonetype

I checked `w_table.iloc[i,4]` and didn't find `NoneType` objects in it. What's the matter could it be?

```
check = ['word']
for i in range(len(w_table)):
    if w_table.iloc[i, 4] != 'Null':
        if w_table.iloc[i, 4] in check:
            w_table = w_table.drop(w_table.index[i])
        else:
            check = check.append(w_table.iloc[i, 4])
        w_table.index = np.arange(len(w_table))
```

After executing above code I am getting following `TypeError`

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-74-40b9156195fa> in <module>()

       2 for i in range(len(w_table)):
       3     if w_table.iloc[i, 4] != 'Null':
       4         if w_table.iloc[i, 4] in check:
       5             w_table = w_table.drop(w_table.index[i])
       6         else:

 TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: But it seems problem is with `NaN`s, missing values in column.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `w_table` looks like and describe what your trying to do?  Generally looping through a DataFrame isn't the best idea and there could be an easier solution here.

Comment: @jezrael there are no 'Nan's in column

Comment: How working `if pd.notnull(w_table.iloc[i, 4])` ?

Comment: @vealkind there are some copies of the raws in table and I need to delete them

Comment: @jezrael the command returns true

Comment: check answer, problem is with append.

Comment: 'check' is None. When using operator `in`, python will look for an iterable. So 'if (...) in check' yields this error if 'check is None'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
check = check.append(w_table.iloc[i, 4])
```

`list.append` is an **in-place operation** and returns `None`. Instead, just use:

```
check.append(w_table.iloc[i, 4])
```

For better performance, use `set` and `set.add`:

```
check = {'word'}
...
check.add(w_table.iloc[i, 4])
```

Even better, you can use vectorised functionality to avoid loops altogether. For this, you should provide a complete example, probably in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).